# Not able to navigate to page2 again when returned from it to Page1 in HTML5 Metro app?

Tags: javascript, html, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

I have used below statement to navigate to page2 from page1's Next button.

document.location.pathname = "page2.html";

I clicked on Home button FROM PAGE2 to return to Page1(document.location.pathname = "PAGE1.html";).And it loaded the page1(home page for me).But when I clicked on Next button FROM PAGE1 again I am not able to navigate to page2 AGAIN .

Comment: Is your code that sets the location being executed? If you set window.location.hfref the url (/page2.html) does that work?

Comment: Second time when I click on next button, the next button clicked event is not firing.window.location.hfref didn't work .When I tried the window.location.href it worked but same issue comes.that is not able to navigate to page2 again.

Comment: How are you attaching the event handler? Does this code work in IE?

Comment: I didnt try this in IE.i have event handler for that button in app.start()

Comment: I don't think app start will be called the second time; that relies on activation from the OS. Try using WinJS.Utilities.ready instead, for attaching your even handlers